# Form texarea to php

Tags: php, html, function

```
    <form name="jobpost" method="POST" action="savepost.php">

    Company Name : <input type="text" name="company-name" placeholder="Company Name"><br>   

    Type Job Title : <input type="text" name="jobtitle" placeholder="Job Title"> <br>
<textarea name="cdata" placeholder="Enter Description" rows="10" cols="5"></textarea> <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="submit">

    </form>
```

I have this form. i want to send this data to php file. but texarea data not come to php. It will show cdata is underfunded.

this is php code

```
<?php 

#Values

$companyName = $_POST["company-name"];
$jobTitle = $_POST["jobtitle"];
$jobCat = $_POST["jobcat"];
$contentData = $_POST["$cdata"];

echo $companyName."<br>".$jobTitle."<br>".$jobCat."<br>".$contentData;

 ?>
```

Comment: Place your textarea outside of the <form></form> and add an attribute pointing to the form. `<textarea name="cdata" placeholder="Enter Description" rows="10" cols="5" form="jobpost"></textarea>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$` from INDEX of POST array near `$_POST["$cdata"]`.

Replace

```
$contentData = $_POST["$cdata"];
```

into

```
$contentData = $_POST["cdata"];
```

Comment: @Shenald please mark tick if you found my answer useful

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
$contentData = $_POST["$cdata"];
```

To

```
$contentData = $_POST["cdata"];
```

**HERE: $contentData = $_POST["$cdata"]; $cdata is PHP variable so it will try to replace the value of $cdata. This method can be used to access $_POST with dynamic variable (just to avoid static data).**

**And in your example you do not have declared any variable with $cdata so PHP interpreter replaced this with empty and it shows *"underfunded"***

Answer (score 0):

When you dont know why something not works, then try use `var_dump($_POST);die;` , you will see what form return and you can analyze your code what is wrong.